# How to save and retrieve the response from the "RESTBuilder" on Total.js platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

Inspired by this post [build a cryptocurrency comparison site- with vuejs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-cryptocurrency-comparison-site-with-vuejs#toc-conditionals)

I want to write a single-page application using the total.js platform to get the coins list from the "coinmarketcap.com" api, and store the response into the database. I've done the following. But I get an error while storing the received information. How can I save the received json file to the database or file system and use it somewhere else?

1- I have written a file called "coins.js” inside the "models" folder containing the following code

```
// For importing
const Fs = require('fs');

NEWSCHEMA('UsdPrice').make(function(schema) {
schema.define('price', Number);
schema.define('volume_24h', Number);
schema.define('percent_change_1h', Number);
schema.define('percent_change_24h', Number);
schema.define('percent_change_7d', Number);
schema.define('market_cap', Number);
schema.define('last_updated', Date);
});

NEWSCHEMA('Coin').make(function(schema) {
schema.define('id', Number);
schema.define('name', 'String(50)');
schema.define('symbol', 'String(40)');
schema.define('slug', 'String(50)');
schema.define('num_market_pairs', Number);
schema.define('date_added', Date);
schema.define('tags', '[String]');
schema.define('max_supply', Number);
schema.define('circulating_supply', Number);
schema.define('total_supply', Number);
schema.define('platform', 'String(20)');
schema.define('cmc_rank', Number);
schema.define('last_updated', Date);
schema.define('quote', '[Object]');
schema.define('USD', '[UsdPrice]');

schema.setSave(function($) {

    var model = $.model;
    var coin = U.extend({}, model.$clean());

    // Extends model
    coin.dateadded = F.datetime;

    NOSQL('coins').insert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(coin)));
  });
});
```

2- I have written a file called “default.js” inside the “controllers” folder containing the following code

```
exports.install = function() {
ROUTE('/', viwe_index);
ROUTE('POST /api/coins/  *coin --> @save');
};

function viwe_index() {

var self = this;

RESTBuilder.make(function(builder) {
builder.url('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest? start=1&limit=2&convert=USD');
builder.header('X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY', 'b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c');
builder.accept('application/json');
builder.header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
builder.GET().plain().exec(function(err, response) {
  //console.log(response);
  AJAX('POST /api/coins/', 'coin', function(response){
  response.$save();
  });
});
}, function() {
  self.view('index');
});
}
```

3- I have written a file called “index.html” inside the “views” folder containing the following code

```
@{layout('')}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CryptoCompare</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta name="robots" content="all,follow" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body { padding: 50px; margin: 0; font:normal 12px Arial; color: gray }
    a { float:left; margin: 0 5px 0 0; font-size: 13px; }
    p { background-color: #F0F0F0; padding: 5px; font:bold 15px Arial; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>CryptoCompareTotal index</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i uncomment the line "//console.log(response);" in "default.js" i get the bellow response , but when i comment it, i get the error.

```
{
"status": {
    "timestamp": "2019-09-23T11:17:47.434Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 10,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
},
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "num_market_pairs": 8058,
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable"
        ],
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "circulating_supply": 17952637,
        "total_supply": 17952637,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "last_updated": "2019-09-23T11:16:35.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 9967.31536844,
                "volume_24h": 12606470860.563,
                "percent_change_1h": -0.0940096,
                "percent_change_24h": -0.677549,
                "percent_change_7d": -3.23074,
                "market_cap": 178939594674.12457,
                "last_updated": "2019-09-23T11:16:35.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1027,
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "slug": "ethereum",
        "num_market_pairs": 5641,
        "date_added": "2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable"
        ],
        "max_supply": null,
        "circulating_supply": 107859213.999,
        "total_supply": 107859213.999,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 2,
        "last_updated": "2019-09-23T11:17:26.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 210.843252214,
                "volume_24h": 7065823660.95811,
                "percent_change_1h": 0.108406,
                "percent_change_24h": -0.423833,
                "percent_change_7d": 9.19434,
                "market_cap": 22741387460.794956,
                "last_updated": "2019-09-23T11:17:26.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `AJAX` is jComponent function, so frontend library, not a backend total.js library.

Please try this code, I don't have API key, so I can't try.

Controller:

```
exports.install = function() {
    ROUTE('/', view_index);
};

function view_index() {

    var self = this;

    RESTBuilder.make(function(builder) {
        builder.url('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest? start=1&limit=2&convert=USD');
        builder.header('X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY', 'b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c');
        builder.accept('application/json');
        builder.header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
        builder.exec(function(err, response) {

            // Here you could change response to your model
            var model = response;

            // Save to database without callback
            // For usage please read docs: https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~global~%24SAVE 
            $SAVE('Coin', model);

            self.view('index');
        });
    });
}
```

Part of schema file:

```
schema.setSave(function($) {
    var model = $.clean();
    // Extends model
    coin.dateadded = F.datetime;
    NOSQL('coins').insert(model);
});
```

Comment: your suggestion work, but save with empty values. (null, "", zero ).my db record: `{"id":0,"name":"","symbol":"","slug":"","num_market_pairs":0,"date_added":null,"tags":[],"max_supply":0,"circulating_supply":0,"total_supply":0,"platform":"","cmc_rank":0,"last_updated":null,"quote":[],"USD":[]}` can you test with this api key please? "07c1f1d1-681a-467e-8558-923da4d815c2"

Answer (score 0):

Please read response, you have array of objects in response.data.

Controller

```
exports.install = function() {
    ROUTE('/', view_index);
    // or
    // ROUTE('/');
};

function view_index() {

    var self = this;

    RESTBuilder.make(function(builder) {
        builder.url('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=2&convert=USD');
        builder.header('X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY', '07c1f1d1-681a-467e-8558-923da4d815c2');
        builder.accept('application/json');
        builder.header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
        builder.exec(function(err, response) {

            var data = response.data;

            data.wait(function(item, next) {

                // Schema save
                $SAVE('Coin', item);

                // Or save directly to NOSQL
                // NOSQL('coins').insert(item);
                next();
            }, function() {
                self.view('index');
            });

        });
    });
}
```

Schema

```
    schema.setSave(function($) {
        var model = $.clean();
        // Extends model
        model.dateadded = F.datetime;
        NOSQL('coins').insert(model);
    });
```